# How to adapt vertex shader for 2D and 3D?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, 2d, glsl

I am working on a particle simulation in 2D which I need to extend to 3D. The C++ code is well adapted in order to support 2D and 3D just by changing a flag, however, I just started learning OpenGL and shaders and would like to know if there is a good approach to make my vertex shader generic.

So far my shader looks like

```
in vec3 vertexPosition;
uniform mat4 MVP;

void main()
{
   gl_Position = MVP * vec4(vertexPosition.xyz,1.0);
}
```

which works fine in 3D, but if I go 2D I need to modify it. One way I thought of solving it is to just have 2 different shaders one for 2D one for 3D and with my flag in C++ choose the appropriate one but I was wondering if there is a better approach to achieve this without having two separate shader files.

Any advice?

Comment: you don't really need to change anything, just set Z to 0 and never rotate around any axis but the Z axis

Comment: Yes I know. If I do 2D I have to set Z to 0, and if I go back to 3D I have to set Z to some value. However I also have to change the type of vertexPosition from `vec3` to `vec2` everytime I want to change the dimension of the simulation.

Comment: Actually, I just tested it and I didn't change the type from vec3 to vec2 and it worked, it makes me think that if I pass a float2 to the vertex shader it will automatically put the z=0 ?

Comment: and it sets `w` to 1 if you declared `vec4` but passed in 2 or 3 floats

Comment: Ok, I think that pretty much helps to solve the issue.

Comment: Where can I read about the default values of the vecX for the shaders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the Z coordinate to 0 which happens automatically when you only pass 2 components for the attribute.

see the [Vertex format](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_format) section of the vertex specification page on the openGL wiki:

> Each attribute index represents a vector of some type, from 1 to 4 components in length. The size​ parameter of the glVertexAttribPointer​ functions defines the number of components in the vector provided by the attribute array. It can be any number 1-4. Note that size​ does not have to exactly match the size used by the vertex shader. If the vertex shader has fewer components than the attribute provides, then the extras are ignored. If the vertex shader has more components than the array provides, **the extras are given values from the vector (0, 0, 0, 1) for the XYZW components**. Note that for double-precision inputs (GL 4.1 or ARB_vertex_attrib_64bit), having more components than provided leaves the extra components with undefined values.